# Mysql, enumerate rows, order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table `domain` with columns `name`,`alexarank`,`ind`.

I know how to enumerate all rows in default order:

```
UPDATE domain SET ind = (SELECT @a := @a + 1 FROM (SELECT @a := 0) s);
```

Please suggest how to enumerate them sorted by alexarank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE domain SET ind = (SELECT @a := @a + 1 FROM (SELECT @a := 0) s) ORDER BY something;
```

As stated in : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html