# Mysql replace NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
data1 data2 data3
data4 NULL  data5
data6 data7 data8
```

I want to delete the NULL field (not the whole row) and the "data7" should go up one row. It should look like this

```
data1 data2 data3
data4 data7 data5
data6       data8
```

Is there a function to delete all NULL fields (not rows) in a database?

Comment: can you show your table structure?

Comment: But then what goes in the empty space? Another `NULL`?

Comment: How do you define "UP"? What is the sorting criteria for the data? The first column? Rows in a table are **not** sorted. A statement like "UP" (or "previous") only makes sense if you also define a sort order for your data.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? It seems like a bad idea to just move data between rows like this. Do your rows not represent any sort of cohesive entities?

Comment: SQL doesn't think of columns as independent entities like that.  Rows are the independent entities; you could easily shift it in a row.  But shifting a value up a column isn't very logical; either you're doing something wrong, or your table structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be good to have your table structure or the purpouse, without it I can give a not so nice solution for your problem:

3 tables
column1(id,col1)
column2(id,col2)
column3(id,col3)

you remove null row in each "colx" row of each table.
then you "recreate" the ids for that table
for example with this
[Mysql, enumerate rows, order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655268/mysql-enumerate-rows-order)

Then if you join the tables, there will be no nulls, and the rows will "go up" to fill the null values

I repeat...this isn't the nicest solution, but that's what I can say with the information you provide